# Stop Excel jumping to try and show whole column when double clicking the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have a situation where I have 3 cells; the third cell is rather long and goes way outside the screen view.

The second column I am working with and I constantly need to copy parts of text from the 3rd column to paste into the 2nd column, however every time I double click the 3rd column so I can copy/paste Excel jumps so it can try and display the whole column and hence every time after I copy the data I have to navigate back to where I was so I can how paste the data.

FYI I am using Office 2010.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't influence this type of auto-scrolling in Excel.

- A workaround could be to decrease third column's width so all your columns fit on one screen.
  You can also wrap text within that column, and force row height to be only one line. This way you'll see only part of the text in that column, but once you double click you will see the whole content.
- another trick is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> once you've selected the text and it'll bring you to the previous cell